# Pattern Matching htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess

I know this should be relatively simple but am having trouble and have read and tried several examples from here but none seem to work.

I need to temporarily stop one particular url displaying results and want
to instead redirect the user to another page.

The URL to match on looks like this:

`http://www.testdomain.com/news/index.php?toptitle=big%2Bend&XMLFILE=http://anotherdomain/item.rss%3Fkeyword%3Dbig%2Bend`

(The URL is longer than the above with more parameters)

But all I want is if the url has:  toptitle=big%2Bend in it then I want to redirect the visitor to another subdirectory

Here's what I have tried:

`Redirect 301 /(toptitle=big%2Bend)$ /block/`

Then I tried:

`RedirectMatch 301 ^/(toptitle=big%2Bend)/?$ /block/`

I have tried it with and without encoding but doesn't seem to be working so must be doing something wrong.

Other things are working in the htaccess file so am a bit stumped now - any help appreciated.. I know it's basic :-(

Thanks in adavance

Comment: Both `Redirect` and `RedirectMatch` only match on the _path_ component of the URL – as does a `RewriteRule`. You need a `RewriteRule` to redirect from the old path to the new target, and precede that with a `RewriteCond` that checks the query string for the parameter=value combination you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply - will certainly remember it for the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} toptitle=big%2Bend
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ block/? [R=301]
```

This requires the rewrite module to be enabled in the main config:

LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

Comment: Thanks Brandon - exactly what I needed and guess I was pretty far off - lesson learnt! It will also no doubt help in the future when Google again warns me for having ads on search pages where the results show an adult image. The search term is ok - just that it returned a 60's calender for sale and the women models are topless - so Google warns me like I know every product for sale!!! Wasted too much time on this and thank you for your help - appreciated!!

Comment: @OLM256 Glad to hear that worked! Some ref docs of helpful: [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) - [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) - [Manipulating querystring](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString)